# AWS SDK C++: Compile with CPP_FLAGS

Tags: amazon-web-services, makefile, cmake, g++, aws-sdk

Is it possible to compile a program using the AWS SDK C++ with *CPP_FLAGS* instead of using *cmake*?

In my case, I only want to add the aws-cpp-sdk-s3 libraries to my program.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to build the SDK without CMake, but once it is built you can use whatever build system you would like to use. All you need is the path to the header files, the libraries, and the cflags that were used to build the library.